# Pixel C on Ubuntu 14.04: no PTP, adb needs to be root

Tags: android, mtp, ptp

I have a Pixel C plugged to a PC. The device is properly recognized by the kernel:

```
[  190.454979] usb 1-1.2.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[  190.550564] usb 1-1.2.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=5203
[  190.550574] usb 1-1.2.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  190.550579] usb 1-1.2.2.4: Product: Pixel C
[  190.550583] usb 1-1.2.2.4: Manufacturer: google
[  190.550588] usb 1-1.2.2.4: SerialNumber: 611900XXXX
```

First, if adb is started as normal user, I get:

```
List of devices attached
611900XXXX  no permissions
```

If adb is started as root, I get (and I can shell into it):

```
List of devices attached
611900XXXX  device
```

**I don't have this problem on my Android 6.0.1 Nexus 5X.**

Moreover, the Pixel C can appear as a PTP device and the Camera folder opens in nautilus. But I never get a standard folder if I chose MTP (File Transfer) connection. Nothing pops up. Again, I have no problem with a Nexus 5X Android 6.0.1 and I can get MTP even if adb is started as normal user.

The device runs latest Android 6.0.1 build ryu-mxc14g.

Something is different on Pixel C from Nexus.

**EDIT 1**

I think the problem is in libmtp which has not been updated for the Pixel devices. I see some patches for Nexus (such as 0x18d1 / 0x4ee2) but there is nothing for 0x5203. That's most likely the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libmtp has not been updated to take into account Pixel C device. Editing /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules and adding the following line fix the problem!

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="5203", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

@gregoiregentil: The suggested fix unfortunately does not work for me. I am running Kubuntu 14.04. My Pixel C is still not recognized as a fully functioning file sharing device. As Camera, yes, immediately, but not for MTP. Any further suggestion or did I overlook something? My Pixel C is not rooted.

And sorry for replying like that. I would have written it as comment, but I still need a higher "reputation" or whatever to do so.

Comment: Did you restart udev or reboot? Does it work with an "old" Nexus device which rule is in udev, such as Nexus 5? You can run udev in verbose mode to see what's happening during plug.